# What builders I really need on an Eclipse Android Project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, workspace, building

Looking for tips to speed my Eclipse, I notice the building process uses all these builders:

- Android resource manager
- Android pre compiler
- Java Builder
- Android Package Builder

Is it really necessary run all them each deploy?

I'm Using MOTODEV Studio for Android 2.1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they weren't necessary, they devs bringing you Android development tools would not have included them. I suggest that you look for performance boosts elsewhere. Builders aren't really meant to be tweaked by end users.

Comment: hmm.. The "Android Tools > Fix Project Properties" option manipulates just _Android Resource Manager_, _Android Pre Compiler_ and _Android Package Builder_. According the answer of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056511/what-does-the-command-fix-project-properties-exactly-do.  
  
Maybe it indicates they don't need run Java Builder once time. If the classes compilation already occurs in _Android Pre Compiler_ for example.  
  
Actually the slowest step is "Building workspace...". I'm looking how to boost this part.

Comment: The answer you reference seems to deal with updating old projects to be compatible with the new version of ADT. It doesn't matter if the old version didn't use Java Builder. It wouldn't have been added in the new version if it wasn't necessary. What would be the point of that?

Comment: Ok, so all them are necessary to compile and run my android app (it answer my question). But I perform _Project > Run as... > Android application_ many times and it's actually taking too many time.

Comment: Java Builder actually compiles your code. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883635/android-compilation-is-slow-using-eclipse) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

What best increased the speed of eclipse for me was to add ram for android programming.
I mean both physical ram and ram settings of eclipse :

in eclipse.ini :

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: Yep, I use this approach too.. I prefer use the Max and Min to the same value, avoiding heap resizing. But in this question I'm asking about the use of builders specifically.

Comment: It's not just about resizing. Having a large heap introduces penalties for instance for garbage collection..