# Using android sdk components from intellij to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin

I downloaded intellij with the android plugin and also Android APIs for the different versions. Now I installed eclipse ADT on the same computer but the Android SDK manager cant find all the APIs the I installed while using Intellij. How can I have eclipse point to the same location to where these Android version APIs are located?

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to find the directory path where the android APIs were saved when you used intellij. It should be under File -> Project Structure, look for android sdk path.

Then, In Eclipse ADT, you can change the location of SDK under Window -> Preferences -> Android.

[image]

Comment: I jsut tried this and I get the error when I try to build something

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'hello2'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: make sure ADT is up to date in eclipse. [please see this for other causes/workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043521/errors-running-builder-android-resource-manager-on-adt).

Comment: ADT is up to date! I jsut downloaded the latest version today

Comment: i am guessing [this looks similar to your build problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096315/mac-error-create-android-project-errors-running-builder-android-resource-man)